# C++ Invalid use of 'this' in non-member function

Tags: c++, templates, this, circular-dependency

I have the error
"**invalid use of 'this' in non-member function**"

What is the correct way to write the code to avoid this error.

tree.h:

```
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

template <typename T>
class Node;

class Tree
{
public:
    Tree();

    template <typename TNodeType>
    Node<TNodeType> elaborate(Node<TNodeType> &node);

    Tree* self();

    void doSomething();
};

template <typename TNodeType>
Node<TNodeType> createNew() {
    Node<TNodeType> model(this); //<-- ERROR HERE
    return model;
}

#endif // TREE_H
```

node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <tree.h>

template <typename TNodeType>
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Tree *tree);

    TNodeType current();

private:
    Tree *_tree;
};

template <typename TNodeType>
Node<TNodeType>::Node(Tree *tree):
    _tree(tree)
{
    _tree->doSomething();
}

template <typename TNodeType>
TNodeType Node<TNodeType>::current()
{
    //some code here
}

#endif // NODE_H
```

**Solved.**

In *tree.h* I skipped the declaration of:

```
template <typename TNodeType>
Node<TNodeType> createNew();
```

And I had forgotten in the definition "*Tree::*" before "*createNew()*"

I agree that this question could have been avoided ;-). Sorry

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: I realized the error. I now want to understand how to solve it.

Comment: You should read up on the meaning of `this` in C++. Also, you need the definition of `Node` before `Tree`, you cannot just forward declare it here. But first things first.

Comment: What is `createNew` trying to achieve anyway?  Why wouldn't potential consumers invoke the `Node<TNodeType>` copy constructor directly?

Comment: With time I realized my mistake. Thank you  to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

`createNew()` is a free function (i.e. not a member of a class), and therefore has no notion of [`this`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm&ei=Fn_nUej1OcSA4gSwg4HADw&usg=AFQjCNF7Pfgr7e7F_8FBhuCh6_Ew5SF15A&sig2=hvofQBeUy-vvUFt5upgn8Q&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bGE).

Comment: Good answer, though I've never heard the term "free function" before.  Is that a common term?  I've only heard it called a "static member function" or "static method".

Comment: Static member functions (or static methods, though the term "method" is unusual in the C++ community) are functions declared inside a class with the keyword static. Free functions are declared outside a class. And yes, that's the usual term for them.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename TNodeType>
Node<TNodeType> createNew() {
    Node<TNodeType> model(this); //<-- ERROR HERE
    return model;
}
```

It's really no member function. `this` is keyword of C++ language, that can be used only in member functions.